# org.JSON.JSONException in Java Application

Tags: java, json, tomcat

I am running a java application on **Apache Tomact 6.0.32** and rrunning successfully and same thing I am running on **Test Server** with same Apache Tomact 6.0.32 config and getting following **exception**, any help will be highly appreciated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.JSON.JSONException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
```

I am already using JSON Parser.jar

Comment: Are you sure you don't need any of these : http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.json.JSONException ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not using any other conflicting jar

Answer (score 0):

JSON lib requires `commons-lang` and other libraries as mentioned below as mentioned [here](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/).

> Json-lib requires (at least) the following dependencies in your class
>   path:
>
> ```
> jakarta commons-lang 2.5
> jakarta commons-beanutils 1.8.0
> jakarta commons-collections 3.2.1
> jakarta commons-logging 1.1.1
> ezmorph 1.0.6
> ```

Are you sure you have added the above libraries.

Answer (score 0):

@Vardan Gupta,You think the tomcat is the same ,but things would not be like the same.

If I were you,I would do like this:

Choice I):copy test server's tomcat 6.0.32 to the environment you run successfully, then test the war in this copy.

Choice II):Or you can try to copy the tomcat you run successfully to the test server and do the new test.
Thus,you would found out things.

In my experience,I would copy tomcat(run successfully copy) to the test server...